# Mongo query, intersect two ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I optimize it? I mean even not a performance, but readability...

It's a stage from the aggregation pipeline.
I have to match a list of search criterias within an object.

500 - is "from" property from the object -> static

1000 - is "to" property from the object -> static

I have to find all groups which intersect with the object.
Also, a user can define "<", ">" as well as "<=", ">=".

It is not always a range, the one comparison operator might be missing, so it has to search +- infinity.

Thanks in advance!

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">=" }, "attributes.value": { "$lte": 500 }
        },
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">" }, "attributes.value": { "$lt": 500 }
        },
        {
          "$and": [
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">=" }, "attributes.value": { "$gte": 500 } },
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">=" }, "attributes.value": { "$lte": 1000 } }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$and": [
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">" }, "attributes.value": { "$gt": 500 } },
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">" }, "attributes.value": { "$lt": 1000 } }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$nin": [">=", ">"] }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": "<=" }, "attributes.value": { "$gte": 1000 }
        },
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": "<" }, "attributes.value": { "$gt": 1000 }
        },
        {
          "$and": [
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">=" }, "attributes.value": { "$lte": 1000 } },
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">=" }, "attributes.value": { "$gte": 500 } }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$and": [
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">" }, "attributes.value": { "$lt": 1000 } },
            { "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$eq": ">" }, "attributes.value": { "$gt": 500 } }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attributes.key": { "$eq": "SIZE" }, "attributes.operator": { "$nin": ["<=", "<"] }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking how to make this query more readable, are you concerned about the performance, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I am not very good in mongo, probably I missed some trick because for me this query looks ambiguous, verbose... 
I hope it can be done more easily